# Node-red very basic questions

Tags: apache, node-red, banana-pi

I need to run a webserver on a Banana Pi M2 zero.

Many questions about Node-Red:

1. Do I need to install apache?
2. When we click on deploy, it's deployed where exactly?
3. Where do I see the deployed website in a web browser?

I can't install node-red on the Banana Pi, but had it installed on my computer and also on a Raspberry Pi:

4. Can I develop on my computer and deploy to the Banana Pi?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you do not need to use Apache. Node-RED is it's own HTTP server, this is used to serve the editor interface and any HTTP endpoints defined in the flow. It can also be configured to serve static content from a provided directory if needed. Depending on what exactly you are planning to do it may be appropriate to use Apache or Nginx as a reverse proxy for Node-RED, but with no detail it is impossible to say.
2. The deploy button pushes any changes made to the flow in the Node-RED editor to the backend runtime.
3. There is no "website" as such. It is possible to build a "website" using Node-RED by either a) adding suitable static files (e.g. html) to the static directory mentioned earlier and creating HTTP end point to using the HTTP-in/HTTP-response nodes to handle dynamic content. b) there are nodes like the node-red-dashboard that provide widgets to both display data and handle input.
4. There is nothing to stop you building a flow on one machine and then copying over the `flow.json` and `flow_creds.json` to another machine to run them, just remember that you will need to make sure any none standard nodes used in the flow are also installed on the second machine for it to run.

Comment: "There is no "website" as such."
Is node-red intended to make machine to machine web communication instead of user to machine?

Comment: Node-RED is an event based, flow programming environment, it can be used for many things, if you want to build a website you can, but there isn't one out of the box